# Image has invisible margin to the right

Tags: html, css, image

## Problem:

The image pushes the text to the right "Other stuff here" all the way to the right. This is caused by me resizing the image. I want the "Other stuff here" text to be directly right of the "brand" text. I think this is caused by me resizing the image.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/99c2wxL5/2/

HTML:

```
<header class="header">
    <nav class="navbar">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/index.php">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/6ZjLmn4.png" class="navbar-brand-image" alt="">
            <span>Brand</span>
        </a>
        <div>
            Other stuff here
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Css:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-content: center;
  background: #333333;
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
  height: 50px; 
}

.navbar-brand {
  margin-right: 1rem;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 25px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
  color: #ead911;
  text-decoration: none; 
}

.navbar-brand-image {
  display: block;
  height: 90%;
  width: auto;
  margin-right: 6px; 
}
```

## What I tried:

I read on the internet this is caused by the image being an inline element. I tried giving it display: block; but this did not change anything. Display flex didn't change anything either.

Other solutions I tried were `float:left`, `vertical-align 0` and `line-height 0` which all didn't help.

Giving the image a width helps but I would prefer not to hard code the width of the image, because the image might change in the future.

Comment: Can't you just put the <div> inside <a>?

Comment: That would make the div clickable, which I don't want. The div will contain the navigation buttons later on.

Comment: I want a small margin between the image and the "Brand" text, this is the margin. The gap between the brand text and the "Other stuff here" text is way bigger, I want to remove this.
And which display flex should I remove? I don't think is is caused by the display flex. (As removing it didn't fix the problem, but did break my layout) Try it out on the jsfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a specific reason you are using `display: flex`? I think this is causing your problems. See https://jsfiddle.net/zz9fta8g/1/.

- removed `display: flex`
- set the "Other stuff here" `<div>` to `display: inline-block`
- removed `display: block` from `.navbar-brand`
- set `.navbar-brand-image` to `vertical-align: middle`

Comment: Yeah display flex was causing the problem. I didn't expect it to cause such a random problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is there any problem if you add width in `.navbar-brand`

```
.navbar-brand {
  margin-right: 1rem;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 25px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
  color: #ead911;
  text-decoration: none; 
  width:120px;
  }
```

May it will helps you.

Comment: This causes the width of the navbar to change, I don't understand how this might help me.
See: https://jsfiddle.net/99c2wxL5/4/

Comment: ohh sorry I was saying about `.navbar-brand` (update)

Comment: See the last line in the OP. This is a temporary solution, but I would like a better one.